# Types not showing up for service reference

Tags: vb.net, web-services, web

I'm integrating one of our apps with a third-party provider's web service.  I've added the service reference, but when I go to dimension a var as one of their types, the types aren't showing up for me in Intellisense.

I'm using VB.NET/VS 2008 on Windows 7 and a 2.0 Framework web site running on local IIS. I have imported System.Web and System.Web.Service in my codebehind.  I also made sure to check the "Always generate message contracts" checkbox.

Anyone have an idea what I need to do to get the types to show up?

Answer (score 8):

Well, I finally found the solution.  First off, I had to update my code base from 2.0 to 3.5 just to get the "Add Service Reference" option to even show up in VS 2008 or 2010.  Once I did that I noticed that the svcinfo files were essentially empty (having only closing tags) and no disco file was being created.

I found an article online with a Windows Phone 7 developer reporting the same problem.  There was a recommendation there to uncheck the option "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" on the Advanced page of the Add Service Reference dialog.  Once I did that everything worked like a charm.

Hopefully this info will benefit others at some point.

SteveDog, thanks for all the ideas and help!

Comment: This worked for me. I had created a simple project to test a 3rd party service which all worked fine. Attempting to add the same reference to the main project resulted in the reference.vb file not being generated correctly. I think this may have been because there were already other service references in the application. Unchecking 'Resue Types' meant that the files were generated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the namespace generated by the web service reference.  For instance, if your client project's namespace is `MyClient` and your web reference is called `MyWebReference`, you'd need to import:

```
Imports MyClient.MyWebReference
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Sounded promising, but still no joy.

Comment: When I added that I got the error "Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'MyClient.MyWebReference (sticking with your naming here, that's not what I actually used) doesn't contain any public member or can't be found. Make sure the namespace or type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

Comment: @Mike Is there a class in the web service project that is tagged with the <WebService> and <WebServiceBinding> attributes?  Does it contain any methods that are tagged with the <WebMethod> attribute?

Comment: Steve, there are no references like that currently in my client app.  Actually, I stand corrected - there is a file called FileWebService in the App_Code folder that one of my co-workers was messing around with.  Just has the "hello world" kinda stuff in it, but it does have those tags.

Comment: @Mike Click the button in your solution explorer to show all files.  Then open the Web References>MyWebReference>Reference.map>Reference.vb file.  That is the designer code that is generated by the web service reference.  You can look in there to see the name of the namespace, classes, and methods that it generated.

Comment: Thanks for the help Steve!  I don't have a "Show All Files" button in Solution Explorer, but I expanded the App_WebReferences folder and "MyWebReference", but there's no vb file.  There's the svcmap, wsdl, disco, a couple svcinfo files and several xsd files

Comment: Just for grins I set up a new project, added a service reference, imported system.web, system.web.services and "MyWebReference" and the service types came right up!

Comment: Yay!  I was going to say, it seems like adding the reference simply failed to work properly for some reason.

Comment: Well, unfortunately it didn't work for my "real" project.....Not sure what the difference could be.

Comment: Try deleting the reference, rebooting, and adding the reference again.  Make sure all the files are not read-only.  Other than that, I'm not sure what to tell you either.

Comment: Still no joy.  One thing I noticed comparing the web.config between the test project and mine - mine had no <ServiceModel> paragraph.  Copied the one from the test and pasted it in mine hoping that would help, but still no difference.